# open the "closed" shadowRoot created outside of my chrome extension

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension, shadow-dom

well google translate extension in chrome, has popup feature, it displays translation of selected word instantly, I wanted to access those translations displayed by popup, but this popup element is shadowRoot("closed"), so javascript cant access its content, I red an article about that subject and author says:

> [But really there is nothing stopping someone executing the following JavaScript before your component definition.](https://blog.revillweb.com/open-vs-closed-shadow-dom-9f3d7427d1af)
> `Element.prototype._attachShadow = Element.prototype.attachShadow; Element.prototype.attachShadow = function () { return this._attachShadow( { mode: "open" } ); };`

Is it possible to change attachShadow method of other extension? if so where should it be executed by my extension? background_script or maybe somewhere. I think each extension has its own enviroment and I have no chane to edit their methods. I wish I'm wrong :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No need to override it.
There's a special method in the content script.

- [Chrome 88+](https://developer.chrome.com/docs/extensions/dom):

  ```
  let shadowRoot = chrome.dom.openOrClosedShadowRoot(element);
  ```
- [Firefox 63](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/openOrClosedShadowRoot):

  ```
  let shadowRoot = element.openOrClosedShadowRoot();
  ```
- Combined:

  ```
  let shadowRoot = chrome.dom?.openOrClosedShadowRoot(element)
    || element.openOrClosedShadowRoot();
  ```

Comment: whow it works, so cool, thank you

Comment: and for firefox?

Comment: @wOxxOm This looks very useful, but i dont understand how i would use it in some actual code. For example if the code on the webpage that the chrome extension is running on has the following code. How would i target shadowtag from the extension to examine its text content?

<parentTag>
  #shadow-root (closed)
  <shadowTag id="textid">Text</shadowTag>
</parentTag>

Comment: You would use standard DOM: element = document.querySelector('parent-tag'); set shadowRoot as shown in this answer; innerElement = shadowRoot.querySelector('shadow-tag'); innerText = innerElement.textContent

Comment: thanks! btw in your answer you have written chrome.dom?.openOrClosedShadowRoot(element)   
is the question mark a typo?

Comment: It's the `optional chaining operator`.