# How to access closed shadow tree?

Tags: google-chrome-extension

I've been trying to print the entire DOM of the current page, including any shadow DOM (user-agent) created by the browser. However, these shadow trees are unable to be found with the following even when they certainly exist in the current page. Does anyone know what might be missing? AFAIK the spec allows Chrome extensions to access browser generated shadow trees. I've tried with a debugger attached as well, but to no avail. Here's the `background.js`:

```js
chrome.action.onClicked.addListener((tab) => {
  chrome.scripting.executeScript({
    target: {tabId: tab.id},
    function: printDOMAndShadowDOM
  });
});

function printDOMAndShadowDOM() {
  function serializeDOM(node) {
    var serializer = new XMLSerializer();
    return serializer.serializeToString(node);
  }

  function exploreAndPrintShadowDOM(node) {
    if (!node) return;

    // Check if the node has a shadow root
    if (node.shadowRoot) {
      console.log('Shadow DOM found: ', serializeDOM(node.shadowRoot));
      // Recursively check for shadow DOM inside the shadow DOM
      exploreNode(node.shadowRoot);
    }

    // If the node has child nodes, explore them
    if (node.childNodes.length) {
      node.childNodes.forEach(exploreAndPrintShadowDOM);
    }
  }

  function exploreNode(node) {
    if (node.nodeType === Node.ELEMENT_NODE) {
      exploreAndPrintShadowDOM(node);
    }
  }

  console.log('Main DOM: ', serializeDOM(document));
  exploreNode(document.body);
}
```

Comment: [How to access shadow-root (user-agent) from context of a chrome extension?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77584820) and a simpler method [for non-useragent shadowRoots](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70490033).